# How to get size of an array in CUDA kernel function?

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA kernel function like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(int a, int b)
{
extern __shared__ unsigned char array[];
//int size = /*size of array*/; = 16
}
```

and in function main I called it:

```
sharedMemSize = 16;
kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize, sharedMemSize>>>(1, 2);
```

How can I get size of shared memory array?
This is the first time I have a question on StackOverflow :) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the size in bytes of your array using: `sizeof(array)`.

Comment: can you do that for an array like `int *pa`??

Comment: No, because that's a pointer. The variable called `array` from the question *is* actually an array, and not a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as a kernel parameter?

```
kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize, sharedMemSize>>>(1, 2, sharedMemSize);
```

Comment: Or a template parameter

Comment: A template parameter for dynamically allocated shared memory?

Comment: Why not? There are usually only a very finite number of shared memory sizes most kernel are actually ever launched with, so a template parameter for the size and a couple of compile time instances can cover those. Having a known  constant can give pretty big performance improvements via improved compiler optimisation. And then the dynamic allocation could be removed all together and replaced with a templated static allocation.